# nbconvert to convert from notebook to Latex/PDF cuts off the dataframe

Tags: pdf, width, converters, dataframe, pdflatex

I have a notebook that displays lots of dataframe tables in HTML format.  However when I used nbconvert to convert the notebook to latex and to PDF, some tables with wider body gets cut off.  I have tried using pd.set_option('display.width', xxxx) but it didn't seem to work.  It seems that the issue is not in the display of the pandas dataframe( the table is displayed just fine on the notebook ), but rather in converting the notebook to Latex/PDF.  Is there anything I can do to resolve  this problem?